# How should i update Drivers in Windows 10 Home In HP laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, updates

How should i update Drivers in Windows 10 Home?

Method 1. Allow Drivers update to be managed by Windows 10 **Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update**

Method 2. Open Properties of **This PC**, click on Device Managers , then select Hardwares listed one by one and click on context menu's **Update driver**

Method 3. Use Hp Support assistant

Method 4. Please recommend any other third party tool like DriverMax but which is **free** and Opensource if possible.

Or you can suggest any other method.

Comment: I would stay away from _Method 4_ unless you cannot find drivers for your system with HP and Microsoft. Your best bet might be _HP Support_, then Microsoft may update from there, if needed. I only update through Device Manager if I have downloaded a package and upzip it.

Comment: Windows recommended approach - Go to Windows Update in Control Panel, check for updates, and then view and install driver updates that are available for your computer.After the first time driver installation,there are not many updates and its quick to identify and install  driver updates with this method.

Comment: I personally use IOBIT driver booster and DriverEasy. Second one is better but with free version your download speed is limited and there is some manual work during update. So I go with IOBIT and after, I use EasyDriver if need be. Windows update won't get you the manufacturers drivers, always search for right drivers manualy or use tools to help you with that, because exact and up to date drivers mean a lot for PCs overal performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I get all drivers from third-party websites or Windows to do it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1237666/should-i-get-all-drivers-from-third-party-websites-or-windows-to-do-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method would be to use the Windows update i.e. your method 1, and if you want to install drivers for your pc you should go to advance settings and check the box that says: **receive updates for other microsoft products**

Comment: Why do you think method 1 is best?

Comment: The drivers are officially recognised by Windows and they are the most stable ones that you can get for your devices. They will also not have any compatibility issues with your devices as well.

Comment: What about going to hardware manufacturer's website then downloading specific driver for my hardware?Is there can be any compatibility issues?

Comment: You can do that, but it will be time consuming and if you dont know your exact model and type it can be more painstaking. While the windows update will automatically detect your device model and find the best driver for it

Comment: I often find that the drivers MS offers for video cards are incompatible.  Nvidia, for example, often licenses  chipsets to other manufacturers.  Using drivers other than the OEM driver (Dell, Lenovo, etc) often results in issues

Comment: @DaveM, for the last 1-2 yrs that i have been configuring and installing windows, I have not received any incompatiblity issues, I would agree that before the windows 10 update 1803 they were some issues, mainly them being outdated, but apart from that they weren't any major issues that I faced